# Probability that Consecutive Partial Sums of Normals are Positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d. standard normals and let define $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k$ to be their partial sums.  Find $\mathbb{P}(S_1,S_2,S_3 >0)$.

---

*What I've Tried*:
We can set up the integral in a couple of different ways; the most straightforward of which would be $$ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int\limits_{0}^\infty \int\limits_{-x_1}^\infty \int\limits_{-x_1 - x_2}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)} \, dx_3 \, dx_2 \, dx_1$$

which I am unsure how to integrate.  It looks like spherical coordinates might work, but I wasn't able to (correctly) write out the region in spherical coordinates.  We can also set up the integral in a different way: if we let $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ and $S = (S_1,S_2,S_3)^T$, then we have $AX = S$ where $$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1
 \end{array} \right).$$ 
If we let $\mathbb{R}_+^3 = \{(x,y,z):x,y,z > 0\}$, then we have $$\mathbb{P}(S \in \mathbb{R}_+^3) = \mathbb{P}(AY \in \mathbb{R}_+^3) = \mathbb{P}(Y \in A^{-1}\mathbb{R}_+^3).$$
This last probability can be calculated from the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int\limits_{0}^\infty\int\limits_{0}^\infty\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\| (x_1,x_2 - x_1,x_3 - x_2)\|^2  } \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3$$

but I don't see how this is better.  If my region were all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it would be easier, since I could just write $(A^{-1})^TA^{-1} = P^T D P$ and send $x \mapsto Px$ to change coordinates nicely.  The problem is that the $P$ that we get turns out to be quite ugly, and it's hard to say what the region looks like after this change of coordinates.

It may be worth mentioning that the simulation I ran seems to suggest that this probability is $\frac{5}{16}$.  This *is* a homework problem, but I'm really stuck, and unsure if there's anything intelligent to do.

Comment: Try thinking geometrically for a little while. The simpler problem of determining the value of $P\{S_1 > 0, S_2 > 0\} = P\{X_1 > 0, X_1+X_2 > 0\}$ has answer $\frac 38$ which can be obtained purely by inspection of a diagram of the plane and the important notion that the joint density of $(X_1, X_2)$ has circular symmetry: **no** double integrals need to be evaluated. Can you extend this notion to three dimensions?  (If you can't, at least you know that the answer you seek is no larger than $\frac 38$.)

Comment: I did notice this but had trouble extending the result to 3 dimensions.  I would have to calculate the volume this region takes up in a ball of volume 1, and that would be my answer.  This is the same as writing the region in spherical coordinates, for the most part.

Comment: I'm not getting $\frac 5 {16}$ - equivalent to $P(S_3>0|S_2,S_1>0)=\frac 5 6$. I got $P(S_3>0|S_1,S_2>0)=\frac 1 2+\frac 1 2(\frac 2 3p+\frac 1 3(1-p))=\frac 2 3+\frac p 6<\frac 5 6$ where $p=P(Y_1+Y_2>Y_3)$ for i.i.d. $Y_i\sim N(0,1)|N(0,1)>0$.

Comment: @A.S., I don't fully follow your calculation.  What events do the probabilities $\frac{2}{3}p$ and $\frac{1}{3}(1 - p)$ correspond to?

Comment: Break up $C=\{S_1,S_2>0\}$ into $A=\{X_1,X_2>0\}$ and $B=\{X_1,X_1+X_2>0,X_2<0\}$ of respective weights $2/3$ and $1/3$. Then $P(S_3|C)=\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 (P(A|C)P(S_3>0|A,X_3<0)+P(B|C)P(S_3>0|B,X_3<0)$ and use symmetry of the normal, that is $(N(0,1)|N(0,1)<0)\sim (-N(0,1)|N(0,1)>0)$.

Comment: I lost an extra $X_1+X_2>0$ condition, so my first comment is void. Reworking.

Comment: After getting rid of conditioning on $Y_1>Y_2$ (through $P(C|D)=\frac {P(C,D)}{P(D)}$), I get $\frac 1 2+\frac 1 2(\frac 2 3p+\frac 1 3\frac{1-p}{1/2})=\frac 5 6$ - just as you estimated.

Comment: @A.S., Awesome.  Thank you so much.  I knew there had to be an intelligent way to do this without messing around with that nasty integral.

Comment: Good. This also suggests that $P(S_k<0|X_k<0, S_1,\dots, S_{k-1}>0)=\frac 1 k$ but bookkeeping gets messy and I suspect there must be an even an easier general symmetry argument.

Comment: @A.S., Numerical calculation seems to agree with that conjecture, as well (I only went up to $k = 10$, though).

Comment: It's too pretty not to hold for all $k$ ;). It would also imply that $P(S_1,\dots,S_n\ge 0)=\Theta(\frac 1 {\sqrt n})$ which agrees with $P(M_n=0)=\Theta (\frac 1 {\sqrt n})$ where $M_n$ is a running maximum/minimum for either a standard Brownian motion or for a simple random walk (as the simplest approximation to the "normal walk" in question).

Comment: Can you run simulations for a different continuous (symmetric) random step to see if the conjecture is distribution-dependent? It's is not for $k=1,2,3$ (pure symmetry arguments) but it seems like it is distribution-dependent for higher $k$ - hence pure symmetry arguments won't work.

Comment: @A.S, I tried it for Uniform, Student's-t (with $1$, $10$ and $100$ degrees of freedom), and Arcsine random variables and it appears to work for them too, somewhat surprisingly (again, I tested up to $k = 10$).

Comment: Computing the quantity in question for a simple random walk (counting each time touching 0 as halving the probability weight of that path) yields $P(SW_4)=\frac {34} {128}$ while for normal random walk (in question) $P(NW_4)=\frac {35}{128}$ by conjecture/computation. Hence my conjecture holds only for the normal RW and no symmetry arguments are possible for $k>3$ as I found out. Asymptotically, $P(SW_n)\sim \sqrt {\frac {2}{\pi n}}$ while $P(NW_n)\sim \sqrt {\frac 1 {n\pi}}$, so inequality reverses at some point.

Comment: How precise are your estimates of $P(W_k)$? The difference for $k=4$ on the order of $\frac 1 {128}$ (as exactly computed above) and could be even less for higher $k$.

Comment: Mine are likely not precise enough to notice such a difference with any significance.

Comment: It turns out my conjecture is correct and holds for ANY continuous symmetric random walk. The result is called [Sparre Andersen Theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1195.pdf) (page 11) and can be written as $P(W_n)=\binom {2n}n 2^{-2n}\sim \frac 1{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. For a simple random walk, if we consider $S_i\ge 0$, we get $P(SW_n)=\binom n {n/2}2^{-n}\sim \sqrt {\frac 2 {\pi n}}$. I wonder if we half the weight of each path each time it touches $0$ (to better approximate continuous case around $0$) if we'd get the same asymptotics as the continuous case.